# how to submit form inside the javascript function?

Tags: javascript

I'm struggling this submit form after clicking the submit button where the submit button is outside the form. Submit button has a click listener which will perform function and I want to submit the form inside the function of the button.
Here is my code..
HTML...

```
    <form action="quiz_insert.php" method="POST" id="myform">
        <input type="hidden" name="checking" id="myScore">
         <button form="myform" id="submit">Submit Quiz</button></br>
    </form>
```

and here is the function inside the javascript.

```
(function() {
 function redirect() {
//JSON.stringify(checkAnswer) is generated in another function.
document.getElementById("myScore").val("MYSCORE");
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}

  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");  
submitButton.addEventListener("click", redirect);
})();
```

Any help is much more appreciated.

Comment: I agree with the answers in wondering why you can't just have the submit button inside the form. But as to why your code isn't working,we would need more information. All your event listener is doing is triggering a `click` event on the `hiddenButton` - which is an `<input>` element (a hidden one at that), which will by default do noting when you click it. So I'm wondering if you'd added any event listeners to that button. I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve here - but if the end goal is to simply subit the form, all you need to do with jQuery is `$("form#submit").submit();`

Comment: `<input type="hidden" type="submit" id="hiddenButton">` - you can not create a “hidden submit button” this way. It is either of type hidden, or type submit button. You can not just put the same attribute on an HTML element twice, that is invalid to begin with.

Comment: ive edited my post but still the next page will not view the output. the way I've create the function is to store an series of array in input type hidden and pass to the action form, but when the action page is loaded there is no array value display. I already use the jQuery $("#myform").submit(); but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Associate the button with the form. You can do that with [the `form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-form):

```
<button form="myform" id="submit">Submit Quiz</button>
```

… it would be better to just put the submit button inside the form in the first place though.

Comment: can the function will still run after clicking the submit button?

Comment: @TimJhan — Well, it will try to run. The errors you have in it will cause an exception to be thrown still.